# vscode key binding !terminalFocus not working after update?

Tags: visual-studio-code

after the update 1.31 this key binding doesnt work anymore.

```
{
        "key": "` `",
        "command": "workbench.action.terminal.focus",
        "when": "!terminalFocus"
    },
    {
        "key": "` `",
        "command": "workbench.action.focusActiveEditorGroup",
        "when": "terminalFocus"
},
```

once in the terminal, instead of going back to editor, it just writes ``.
I've seen that they mentioned something new about `terminal.integrated.commandsToSkipShell` , so I assume it has something to do with this, but I dont know how to make it work anyway.
I tried adding a new preference like:

```
terminal.integrated.commandsToSkipShell:["workbench.action.terminal.focus"]
```

but nothing.

Comment: How about terminal.integrated.commandsToSkipShell:["workbench.action.focusActiveEditorGroup" ]  ?

Comment: I tried that one also, but nothing. I even wrote terminalFocus and all them together but nothing

Comment: Your desired keybinding is 2 backticks together or is there a space(s) between them - it is hard to tell?

Comment: It is puzzling, I tried various combinations and it never worked with your keybinding.  Something like "alt-x" works just fine though in your code.

Comment: I don't press a space between them, but on the json file it shows a space. It works with the version 1.30 and yes other combinations of keys works. strange

Answer (score 0):

With [VSCode 1.52 (Nov. 2020)](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/d3a4a52f99f321696baf803655fdc37af4a64994/release-notes/v1_52.md#keybindings-management), you now have:

> ### Terminal Keybindings Management
>
> By default, keybindings are dispatched to the workbench instead of the terminal as specified in `terminal.integrated.commandsToSkipShell`.
> This notification informs the user when they have entered a keybinding corresponding to one of these commands and provides the option to configure the relevant settings.
>
> To send most keybindings to the terminal instead of the workbench, set `terminal.integrated.sendKeybindingsToShell`.
>
> [image: Send Keybindings to Shell -- https://media.githubusercontent.com/media/microsoft/vscode-docs/vnext/release-notes/images/1_52/terminal-keybindings-notification.gif]